# Extracting from csv files with python code

Tags: python, csv

i have a csv file which contains extracted tweets from some tweeter id. i need to get rid of first 3 columns i get before the original tweets text. e.g.

> ArvindKejriwal,630345258765697024,2015-08-09 11:49:55,"RT @NitishKumar: No better place to start than from the land of Budhha. We commit no tickets to criminals. Now,show courage & commit to thi…"

I just want to extact text after "RT...." and store in another csv file. Please suggest...i have this in bunch say some 2k rows. how to achieve this?

my sample code:

```
import csv
inputCSV = open(r'C:\\...\\ArvindKejriwal_tweets.csv', 'rb')
outputCSV = open(r'C:\\...\\\\OUTPUT.csv', 'wb')
appendCSV = open(r'C:\\...\\\\OUTPUT.csv', 'ab')
appendCSV11 = open(r'C:\\...\\\\OUTPUT_Final.csv', 'ab')
cr = csv.reader(inputCSV, dialect = 'excel')
cw = csv.writer(outputCSV, dialect = 'excel')
ca = csv.writer(appendCSV, dialect = 'excel')
ca_final=csv.writer(appendCSV11, dialect='excel')
for row in cr:
    if row or any(row) or any(field.strip() for field in row):
        ca.writerow(row)

f=csv.reader(open('C:\\..\\OUTPUT.csv','rb'))
for column in f:
     if column or any(column) or any(fields.strip() for fields in column):
        ca_final.writerow(column[3])

# close files
inputCSV.close()
outputCSV.close()
appendCSV.close()
```

Comment: What you have tried till now?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code writing service, please show your efforts

Comment: @tec_abhi by what have you tried they are asking code sample

Comment: sorry guys...please see my sample code above...if instead of ca_final.writerow(column[3]) i give print column[3] i get my output..over screen and i need to take it to other csv file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to close the file objects before opening it again.

```
for row in cr:
    if row or any(row) or any(field.strip() for field in row):
         ca.writerow(row)

# add these two lines
outputCSV.close() 
appendCSV.close()

f=csv.reader(open('C:\\..\\OUTPUT.csv','rb'))
for column in f:
     if column or any(column) or any(fields.strip() for fields in column):
         ca_final.writerow(column[3:]) # put a colon here

# close files
inputCSV.close()
outputCSV.close()
appendCSV.close()
```

column[3:] will skip first three columns.

Comment: thank you Karan, it worked. I am new to python and didnt realize this. Thanks again for the help...!!

Comment: @tec_abhi you could accept his answer by clicking the tick arrow